# Validation within a Loop

Tags: java, validation

I am trying to run a validation in my while loop to make sure an ID is not already used but the program keeps skipping over my validation - any advice on how to get the validation to work?

```
public void addinventory items(ArrayList<Inventory> mv) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Choose one of the following menu options (1,2,or 3): 
\n1. Update an item in the inventory");
System.out.println("2. Add a new inventory item");
System.out.println("3. Exit to main menu\n");
int choice = scan.nextInt();

while (choice == 2) {
    System.out.println("What is the ID of the inventory item?");
    String inventoryID = scan.nextLine();
    while (checkId(mv, inventoryID)) {
        System.out.println("This ID already exists, enter a different ID: ");
        inventoryID = scan.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("How many inventory items do you wish to add?");
    int numinventory items = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the description?");
    String desc = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How many stocks to did you purchase?");
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the cost of the inventory item?");
    double cost = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is the value of the inventory item?");
    double value = scan.nextDouble();

    Inventory inventory = new Inventory(inventoryID.toUpperCase(), desc, num, cost,
            value);

    mv.add(inventory);
    numinventory items--;

}
```

Comment: You say its skipping the validation do you know that because a break point in the checkId function is never hit or because the look is never entered even when you enter the same Id?  If the answer is the latter than it may be that the checkId function does not accurately compare the two and you should upload that code to your question.

Comment: Where's checkId method and what is 'mv' variable?

Comment: Also note that you add the ID as inventoryID.toUpperCase() and you may be checking on lowerCase

Comment: Infinite loop since `choice` is never modified. And what is the construct `int numinventory items` supposed to mean?